# Dispatching delegate callback to main queue, from another queue, AVFoundation

Tags: ios, multithreading, avfoundation

I am working on a camera that is wrapped up in a base viewController, with a delegate style interface for callbacks, so all I have to do as a client is subclass the camera view controller, implement the delegate methods, and add the UI buttons.
My question is about recording video. Video recording is started on a unique background task to ensure that the recording can be written to a temporary file. This is done on my 
`private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.andrewferrarone.sessionQueue")` session queue:

```
public func startRecording()
{
    guard let movieFileOutput = self.movieFileOutput else { return }

    //get video preview layer's video orientation on main queue
    guard let videoPreviewLayerOrientation = self.previewView.videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation else {
        print("handleRecord: videoPreviewLayer is nil")
        return
    }

    self.sessionQueue.async {

        if !movieFileOutput.isRecording {
            if UIDevice.current.isMultitaskingSupported {

                self.backgroundRecordingID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
        }

        //update orientation on the movie file output video connection before recording
        let movieFileOutputConnection = self.movieFileOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            movieFileOutputConnection?.videoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerOrientation

        //start recording to a temporary file:
        let outputFileName = UUID().uuidString
        let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
            movieFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath), recordingDelegate: self)
        }
    }
}
```

so the recording is setup as a background task dispatched to self.sessionQueue. When I stop recording I receive an `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` method. In this method, I want to callback my delegate with the filepath, and then cleanup. How do I ensure that the delegate can persist the recording from the temporary file path before cleanup happens and the temporary file is removed?

```
 public func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!)
{
    //cleanup func for later
    func cleanup()
    {
        let path = outputFileURL.path

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Could not remove file at url: \(outputFileURL), error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        if let currentBackgroundRecordingID = self.backgroundRecordingID {
            self.backgroundRecordingID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

            if currentBackgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(currentBackgroundRecordingID)
            }
        }
    }

    var success = true

    if error != nil {
        print("Movie file finishing error: \(error)")
        success = ((error as NSError).userInfo[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey] as AnyObject).boolValue
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.delegate?.camera(self, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt: outputFileURL, success: success)
    }

    cleanup()
}
```

So I called my delegate back on the main queue with the results, but then I need to call `cleanup()` should I do this on the main queue right after calling back my delegate? is this safe? or if I leave it the way it is now, then we are on `self.sessionQueue`, and I am unsure if `cleanup()` will happen before the delegate method implementation has time to persist the recording. If anyone can give me some insight into what is going on and what would be the safest thing to do here, that would be great. According to apple, the documentation says do not assume that `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt` method is called on a specific thread. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.delegate?.camera(self, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt: outputFileURL, success: success)
    self.sessionQueue.async {
        cleanup()
    }
}
```

I think that would be the standard way of handling this situation. When the delegate method finishes, you assume that the delegate is done with the file (or copied it somewhere else).